# Illegal mix of collations (latin1 and utf8)

Tags: mysql, sql

Cheers, is there any way to mix a collations (latin1 and utf8) in mysql statement? I have a function which replaces umlauts with normal letters, but sadly it's not working with the `n̈` as it is not in utf8 I guess.

For example this is working fine

```
SET TextString = REPLACE(TextString, 'ä', 'a');
```

and this one isn't:

```
SET TextString = REPLACE(TextString, 'n̈', 'n');
```

The error:

[image]

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: The short answer is no.  You need to pick a single collation that actually covers your needs.

Comment: TextString collation?

Comment: @jarlh TextString is a result of selecting a varchar value from a table which collation is utf8, so I would guess it's also utf8.